# Defrosting: How long should food be kept in refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, defrosting

I am trying to defrost some meals by placing them in a refrigerator.

The meals are a variation of salmon/halloumi + rice + greens

How long should it be placed in the refrigerator? Does it depend on how long it's been frozen?

Comment: what "meal' are we talking about ? normally, we defrost in the fridge until thawed (or close to)

Comment: @Max edited the question - meals like salmon + rice + greens

Comment: The moment the food is thawed, the rules for safe storage times in the fridge apply, which is already covered [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer). Or did you mean “how long does it take for the food to thaw”?